# SQL Query to continuously bucket data

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions, average

I have a table as follows:

```
Datetime              |  ID   |  Price  |  Quantity
2013-01-01 13:30:00       1       139        25
2013-01-01 13:30:15       2       140        25
2013-01-01 13:30:30       3       141        15
```

Supposing that I wish to end up with a table like this, which buckets the data into quantities of 50 as follows:

```
Bucket_ID  |  Max   |   Min   |   Avg  | 
1             140       139       139.5
2             141       141       141
```

Is there a simple query to do this? Data will constantly be added to the first table, it would be nice if it could somehow not recalculate the completed buckets of 50 and instead automatically start averaging the next incomplete bucket. Ideas appreciated! Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what your desired "bucketing algorithm" is. Where is the "50 numbers" reflected in the example  final table?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity...the bucketing is on the 'number' column...25+25 creates the ID 1 row in the 2nd table. ID 2 in the 2nd table is purely a max/min/avg based on the 3rd line of the 1st table...eventually more rows will be added to the 1st table and this query should reflect that and change row 2 of the 2nd table accordingly.

Comment: What if the quantity being inserted is greater than 50? How is that then broken up? May I suggest `Quantity` or `Count` to be a much better column name than `Number`, which does not imply that the value's magnitude is meaningful? (For examples think of order number, parking space number,  and so on.) Also, I think `ID` could use some thought, too.

Comment: I agree, if the number is greater than 50 then technically it won't fit into the bucket. If it just assumes it's 50 that would be fine.

Comment: But you still haven't really answered the question: what if the bucket already has 15 in it and you are adding 26? Or any combination thereof? What if the bucket has 5 items appearing at the same DateTime value (or will that be guaranteed to never happen?)

Comment: If the bucket already has 15 in it and 26 is added that would make the last bucket recalculate as it only has information based on a quantity of 41.

Comment: Yes... There could be timestamps that are the same. .. In which case multiple buckets should be created for each 50 accumulation

Answer (score 0):

You may try this solution. It should work even if "number" is bigger than 50 (but relying on fact that avg(number) < 50).

```
select
bucket_id,
max(price),
min(price),
avg(price)
from 
(
select 
price,
bucket_id,
(select sum(t2.number) from test t2 where t2.id <= t1.id ) as accumulated
from test t1

join 

(select
rowid as bucket_id,
50 * rowid as bucket 
from test) buckets on (buckets.bucket - 50) < accumulated 
and buckets.bucket > (accumulated - number))

group by
bucket_id;
```

You can have a look at this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/4c63c/1 if it is what you want.

Comment: Note that this won't handle issues where the value is greater than 50, or the sum of the values for the current bucket don't add up to 50.

Comment: If a single row or a combination of two or more rows forces the bucket to hold more than 50 this is fine.  The last bucket is allowed to be incomplete and hold a quantity less than 50

Comment: @ErikE - Can you please share specific case when it won't work? It seem to work for me in cases you mentionet, only condition that needs to be fullfilled is avg(number) < 50 for source table.

Comment: Here's [a fiddle that demonstrates](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/21947/1). If the values don't add up nicely to 50, your query blows up. Notice that `t1.id` is included in two separate buckets (1 and 2) incorrectly.

Comment: Ok, I thought that it should be that way - that if cummulated - number  is in bucket x and cummulated in bucket x + z that price should be taken into account for all those buckets.. if not, then of course it is not correct